# pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Not a Feather V1 or Arrow IPC file

Tags: python-3.7, pyarrow, feather

Python 3.7 feather-format==0.4.1 throws error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./cv.py", line 86, in <module>
    get_training('HeLa-S3'),
  File "./cv.py", line 19, in get_training
    feather.read_dataframe(f'{cell_line}-training.feather').set_index(['chr1', 'x1', 'x2', 'chr2', 'y1', 'y2'])
  File "/home/bade/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/feather.py", line 208, in read_feather
    return (read_table(source, columns=columns, memory_map=memory_map)
  File "/home/bade/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/feather.py", line 230, in read_table
    reader.open(source, use_memory_map=memory_map)
  File "pyarrow/feather.pxi", line 67, in pyarrow.lib.FeatherReader.open
  File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 123, in pyarrow.lib.pyarrow_internal_check_status
  File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 85, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Not a Feather V1 or Arrow IPC file
```

Could anybody help?

Comment: Can you share the file? Do you know how the file was created?

Comment: This is followed up at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-18226